# In R when using accessor "[", what is the default behavior when using on data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

When using

```
?'[.data.frame'
```

I got the following example in the help:

```
> sw <- swiss[1:5, 1:4]  # select a manageable subset
> 
> sw[1:3]      # select columns
             Fertility Agriculture Examination
Courtelary        80.2        17.0          15
Delemont          83.1        45.1           6
Franches-Mnt      92.5        39.7           5
Moutier           85.8        36.5          12
Neuveville        76.9        43.5          17
> sw[, 1:3]    # same
             Fertility Agriculture Examination
Courtelary        80.2        17.0          15
Delemont          83.1        45.1           6
Franches-Mnt      92.5        39.7           5
Moutier           85.8        36.5          12
Neuveville        76.9        43.5          17
> sw[4:5, 1:3] # select rows and columns
           Fertility Agriculture Examination
Moutier         85.8        36.5          12
Neuveville      76.9        43.5          17
```

I didn't find the help document clear on how the above is happening. If I just supply one value or comma and a value that indicates just columns?

However if I put a comma after the first value in the brackets, that value now indicates the records to return? Is the default to return all columns when not specified?

For example:

```
> sw[1:3,]
             Fertility Agriculture Examination Education
Courtelary        80.2        17.0          15        12
Delemont          83.1        45.1           6         9
Franches-Mnt      92.5        39.7           5         5
```

I get all columns - but again I don't see where that is specified in the help. Is there better official documentation out there?

Comment: You can study the source code if that would make it easier `getS3method("[","data.frame")`. Maybe you can also look at the docs for `Extract`

Comment: The source code is too low level and the docs for Extract has the same problem, it almost reads identical to the R help. Appreciate the additional options though.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this is present in different help files. To the question -

```
If I just supply one value or comma and a value that indicates just columns?
```

Yes, from `?"[.data.frame"`

> When [ and [[ are used with a single vector index (x[i] or x[[i]]), they index the data frame as if it were a list.

Dataframes are list with columns being elements of the list hence the subsetting takes place here as if you are subsetting a list.

---

For

```
sw[1:3,]
I get all columns - but again I don't see where that is specified in the help
```

In `?Extract`

> An empty index (a comma separated blank) indicates that all entries in that dimension are selected

Comment: Thanks Ronak, how did the help files answer though when you supply two values it now becomes rows and columns? Also the default of the columns when you don't specify?

Comment: @MilesMorales So when you supply two values it is row and column but when there is only one value it subsets the dataframe as a list where each column is an element in the list.

Comment: Understood, but I'm asking where is this addressed in the documentation? I can deduce that by the examples and by practice, but I don't see where that's documented nor the default of the columns returned for example when you do "x[i, ]"

Comment: @MilesMorales I think that it is already present in my answer. In `?Extract`,  `An empty index (a comma separated blank) indicates that all entries in that dimension are selected`

Comment: So for example when you only put i, for example x[i] in my above example, it only brought back 3 columns, as opposed to all 4 columns - why did it default to 3? That I don't see anywhere in the documentation.